# How to sanitize JSON by jq?

Tags: jq

The command `jq . generaldq_tabelas_novas.json` is the identity, I need it, but using `-nc` option ... But any, `-n` or `-nc` **returns null** on `jq -nc . generaldq_tabelas_novas.json`.

Seems a **bug** because `--help` say   *jq [options] filter file*.

Comment: You can answer `jq --compact-output  . in.json > out.json`. The Help text, in fact, is not good ("help text BUG"). I must read https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man jq`:

```
   o   --null-input/-n:

       Don't read any input at all! Instead, the filter is run once using
       null as the input. This is useful when using jq as a simple
       calculator or to construct JSON data from scratch.
```

This means `jq` won't even read your file when `-n` is used.  This is not a bug, because the synopsis says

```
jq [options...] filter [files...]
```

That is, the file operand(s) are optional.

For compact output, you should use

```
jq -c . generaldq_tabelas_novas.json >newfile.json
```